# pass class of models with javascript textboxes in mvc form to ajax function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

i have a class of models:

```
    public class MyPhoneBookModel
     {
       public ContactsModel Contacts { get; set; }
       public ContactTypesModel ContactTyeps { get; set; }
       public GroupModel ContactGroups { get; set; }
       public ExtraContactsModel ExtraContacts { get; set; }
     }
```

in my partial view , i use it in form to create new contact, and i add 4 textbox with javascript after **"phones" , "emails", ...**

I want to pass my form with this model plus value of javascript textboxes to javascript function that uses ajax.

what should I do?

---

**Update:**

This function adds textboxes for adding more phone numbers. this repeated for emails, addresses and etc.
      function AddPhone() {

```
    if (phoneCounter > 5) {
        alert("You can register just 5 phones!");
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + phoneCounter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>' + 'تلفن ' + phoneCounter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="PhoneTxt ' + phoneCounter +
          '" id="PhoneTxt' + phoneCounter + '" value="" >');


    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#PhoneGroup");
    phoneCounter++;
}
```

THis is **"_AddContactPartial"** :

```
 @model SmsMenu.Models.MyPhoneBookModel
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "AddContacts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 //firstname,lastname and other fields

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contacts.PhoneNum)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contacts.PhoneNum)
    <input type="button" class="ContactAddBtn" onclick="AddPhone()" />
</div>
<div id="PhoneGroup"></div>
//email ,address and other fields same phone.
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="AddNewContact(passValue)" />
</p>

 }
```

I don't know how can i send form with its model and javascript textboxes value as **"passValue"** of **AddNewContact(passValue)**. Thanks...

Comment: can you provide more code please (js and your partial view)?

Comment: @FrancoisBorgies I have edited my post and added codes.